# How can I select a child element of the current element in an each loop?

Tags: jquery, loops, nested-loops

In pseudo-CSS this would look something like this:

```
current_element .text_container {
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do this with jQuery. Something along the lines of:

```
boxes.each(function() {
   console.log( jQuery(this).('.text_container').height() );
});
```

Comment: Can you post some actual code? This hypothetical stuff is too ambiguous.

Comment: @j08691 Sure! Here is the actual thing I'm working with: http://jsfiddle.net/bernk/NBnW9/6/

Comment: I'm trying to equalize the height of the .deeplink_text DIVs per .article DIV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange, I had a question extremely similar to this earlier today. Anyway, try this:

```
$('.mod_article').each(function () {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $('div.ce_deeplink div.deeplink_text ', this).each(function () {
        if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) maxHeight = $(this).height();
    });
    $('div.ce_deeplink div.deeplink_text',this).height(maxHeight);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NBnW9/8/)**

Comment: This works, but I would really appreacite if you could explain this part to me: $('div.ce_deeplink div.deeplink_text ', this)

Comment: That runs `.each` on the `div.ce_deeplink div.deeplink_text` divs relative to the containing `.each` of `.mod_article`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly based on your fiddle, what you need is:

```
$(this).find(".deeplink_text")
```

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/NBnW9/7/

Answer (score 0):

```
boxes.each(function() {
   console.log( $(this).children('.text_container').height() );
});
```

Comment: Of course not you have to iterate and the children probably. Are they all with the same height?